# Kendo UI Grid built using fluent, client template for loop

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

All I have a Kendo grid built using the fluent grid builder. In one of my client templates, I need to iterate over a collection that is being returned. Here is the suspect line:

```
c.Bound(x => x.EventFormats).Width(300).ClientTemplate("# if(EventFormats != undefined && EventFormats.length > 0){ for(var formatIndex=0; formatIndex < EventFormats.length; formatIndex++){ console.log(i) } } #").EditorTemplateName("Formats");
```

The problem is that when I introduce the `for` loop, all hell breaks loose and it loops hundreds of thousands of times (after 300k I gave up and killed the process).

If I do this:

```
c.Bound(x => x.EventFormats).Width(300).ClientTemplate("# if(EventFormats != undefined && EventFormats.length > 0){ console.log(EventFormats.length) } #").EditorTemplateName("Formats");
```

It correctly returns the number of items I'm expecting in the collection. Only 4 of the records that are being returned will have the collection to begin with, and the maximum number of items in any collection is 2 (although it could be more).

I'm not really sure why it is loosing it's mind when I introduce the for loop and any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the JSON object that is getting produced: 

`[{
"Id":85,
"FormatTypeId":34,
"Name":"35mm",
"Created":"/Date(1447265241983)/",
"CreatedBy":"system",
"Modified":null,
"ModifiedBy":null,
"FormatType":null
},
{
"Id":83,
"FormatTypeId":34,
"Name":"16mm",
"Created":"/Date(1447265241737)/",
"CreatedBy":"system",
"Modified":"/Date(1453243258067)/",
"ModifiedBy":"system",
"FormatType":null
}]`

Comment: Does it still happen if you use a `for .. in` construction like `for (var key in EventFormats) { console.log(EventFormats[key]) }` ?

Comment: @BradWestness The way the JSON object is being composed means there are additional keys, so using `for .. in` would mean an even more complicated loop. I'd have to check that the key's index within the object is less than the `length` property. I'll update the question with the JSON object.

Comment: show `EventFormats` json

Comment: I've update the question with the JSON but wanted to also let everyone know that I've come up with a solution which I also posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure as to *why* it was looping 300k+ times, but I did come up with a workable solution.

My KendoGrid template now has this line:

```
c.Bound(x => x.Formats).Width(300).ClientTemplate("#=$.generateFormatList(Formats)#");
```

Then in my JS file, I just wrote the `generateFormatList` function like so:

```
$.generateFormatList = function (formats) {
    var template = '';
    if (formats != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < formats.length; i++) {
            if (i !== 0) {
                template += ", ";
            }
            template += formats[i].Name;
        }
    }
    return template;
}
```

That works like a champ. Not sure why but apparently Kendo can't handle `for` loops inside the `ClientTemplate` all that well.